# Converting a datetime to date in iEF

Tags: entity-framework

I have this Linq statement that runs as expected in LinqPad (using Linq to SQL) but when I bring it into my C# app using EF 6, I get an error saying that cd.LogTimestamp.Date (in the GroupBy statement) is not supported. I'm attempting to convert a datetime2 value to a date value for group by purposes.

```
 helper.GetDbContext().SiteLog
     .Where( sl => sl.SiteId == 3 )
     .GroupBy( cd => new { cd.SiteId, cd.LogTimestamp.Date } )
     .Select( g => new DailyTraffic()
     {
         SiteId         = g.Key.SiteId,
         TrafficDate    = g.Key.Date,
         NewUsers       = g.Count( row => row.IsNewUser ),
         ReturningUsers = g.Count( row => row.IsReturningUser ),
         TotalUsers     = g.Count( row => row.IsNewUser ) + g.Count( row => row.IsReturningUser ),
         PageViews      = g.Count( row => row.IsPageView )
     } )
     .OrderBy( g => g.SiteId ).ThenBy( g => g.TrafficDate )
     .ToList();
```

Is there a preferred way to convert a `datetime2` value to a `date` value in EF 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this QA ( [how to use entity framework to group by date not date with time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963317/how-to-use-entity-framework-to-group-by-date-not-date-with-time) ) as a guide, you'll want to use `EntityFunctions` so you can use built-in SQL Server functions directly, this does of course mean your application won't be immediately portable to other databases.

```
.GroupBy( cd => new { cd.SiteId, EntityFunctions.TruncateTime( cd.LogTimestamp ) } )
```

Comment: As `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` is marked as `Deprecated`, `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime` is replaced.