# LINQ - grouping by date causes NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to display a grouped number of connections to a service in an MVC view.

The issue I am having is when I try to check how many items were returned for paging purposes, I get a System.NotSupportedException

> > The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Here is my IQueryable method

```
private IQueryable<ConnectionItem> ListItems(DataContext dataContext)
{
    return
        from conn in dataContext.Connections
        join cfg in dataContext.Configurations on conn.ConfigID equals cfg.ConfigID
        join u in dataContext.Users on cfg.UserID equals u.UserID
        where conn.Successful && u.AccountEventID == 123
        group 1 by conn.CreatedDate.Date into g
        select new ConnectionItem
        {
            CreatedDate = g.Key,
            NumberOfConnections = g.Count(),
        };
}
```

Here is ConnectionItem

```
public class ConnectionItem
{
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfConnections { get; set; }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
var items = ListItems(dataContext);
var total = items.Count() // this causes the exception
```

My end result should be a collection of dates, such as 2017-01-10 and the number of connections made on that day.

Comment: ```Date``` is a property of the ```DateTime``` object, which is calculated at runtime and cannot be directly translated into SQL for evaluation on the server by the LINQ provider implementation.

There may be a method in ```SqlFunctions``` that can be used to write the query in such as way to allow this to be evaluated by the server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456828(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/q/20963317/861716

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is truncate time then use [`DbFunctions.TruncateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220142(v=vs.113).aspx) method:

```
//...
group 1 by DbFunctions.TruncacteTime(conn.CreatedDate) into g
//...
```