# Get the ISO format of DateTime in one go

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to read data from an MS SQL database and make it available for an interface in text form. With EF6 (& .NET 4.7.2) I now want to read all required values and make them available cleaned.

Among them there is also a date, which is available in the database as DateTime.

```
[DateOfBegin] [datetime] NULL
```

I would like to bring this date now in a step from SQL with EF6 into the ISO format `yyyyMMdd`.
In SQL this can be done with the following query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), DateOfBegin,112) from Contact
```

How can I solve this in C# without calling .ToList() first?

```
context.Contacts
   .Select(c => new InterfaceObject()
   {
      DateOfBegin = // CONVERT(char(10), DateOfBegin,112)
   }
   .ToList();
```

Does anyone see a way to solve this directly? ... Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20965042/993547 might be a start. Not sure if there is another function to do what you want.

Comment: why don't use `DateTime` as datatype for `DateOfBegin` in `InterfaceObject`? Then you can format it as you want....

Comment: Entity Framework isn't meant to be a replacement for SQL, there are plenty of things you can do using SQL that is either impossible or very hard to do using EF. One of those things is more specific formatting like this, and the (likely) reason for this is that it's not the purpose of the data layer to do this formatting, you should do it further up the stack, before you present it to the user. So @Mat's advice is probably the best one, keep it as `DateTime`, format it later.

Comment: @Mat: Thank you for pointing that out. This would be a good opportunity for Plan B.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: Do you think that this conversion is currently not possible at all?

Comment: The conversion is possible for example if you use a view or storedproc. But why? guess this is a XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I don't know whether it is impossible or not, I just know that EF isn't *meant* to be able to handle this kind of thing because it is "the wrong kind" of thing to ask it to do. This is certainly an opinion, but I understand it to be the opinion of most that maintain EF, that you're not supposed to massage the data for user presentation in your EF query, this should be handled above that layer.