# How to select closest date from today using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

I have a MySQL database like this

```
Id    Name     StartTime
1     test1    2021-02-21 08:15:00
2     test2    2021-02-11 18:00:00
3     test3    2021-02-24 14:00:00
4     test4    2021-02-10 10:30:00
5     test5    2021-02-23 09:00:00
6     test6    2021-02-26 16:00:00
7     test7    2021-02-23 12:00:00
8     test8    2021-02-15 17:00:00
```

I want to get 5 closest date from today (2021-02-20).
I expected a result like this :

```
2021-02-26
2021-02-24
2021-02-23
2021-02-21
2021-02-15
```

I tried with this code :

```
var result = _context.EventItems
                .FromSqlRaw("Select * from Event ORDER BY ABS(`StartTime` - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) LIMIT 5")
                .Select(e => e.StartTime.Date)
                .ToList();
```

and the result is :

```
2021-02-24
2021-02-23
2021-02-23
2021-02-21
2021-02-15
```

The problem is the duplicate 2021-02-23. How can I do to resolve my problem? Thank you !!

Comment: You need to use group by when you want to generate a single sql row out of many. See here for a specific example for the date problem... https://stackoverflow.com/a/20965042/2381899

Comment: use `ORDER BY StartTime DESC` and `GROUP BY StartTime`

Comment: @Strawberry, how is it nonsense, it's what `DISTINCT` is for. `The SELECT DISTINCT statement is used to return only distinct (different) values.`.

Comment: I don't have MySQL installed, you could at least explain why and educate. Instead of just downvoting and calling it nonsense.

Comment: @LeeStevens https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd8f6712038f873b0b6508f0f20fe83c

Comment: @Strawberry, cool - i didn't know they had one of these online version for online too. You are correct, you can't use `DISTINCT` this way for this query. Now OP and myself have learnt something today!

Comment: @LeeStevens The point is, DISTINCT doesn't address the OP's problem, which is a misunderstanding of how MySQL's mathematical operators treat dates. As for online tools, actually I prefer db-fiddle.com, but anyway, I digress...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following; I've used '12:00:00' (as opposed to '00:00:00') as the comparison time because it seems more intuitive to me that the 24th is closer to the 20th than the 15th is.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
,start_time DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table  VALUES
(1,'test1','2021-02-21 08:15:00'),
(2,'test2','2021-02-11 18:00:00'),
(3,'test3','2021-02-24 14:00:00'),
(4,'test4','2021-02-10 10:30:00'),
(5,'test5','2021-02-23 09:00:00'),
(6,'test6','2021-02-26 16:00:00'),
(7,'test7','2021-02-23 12:00:00'),
(8,'test8','2021-02-15 17:00:00');

SELECT *
     , SEC_TO_TIME(ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-02-20 12:00:00')))x  
  FROM my_table 
 ORDER 
    BY x ;
+----+-------+---------------------+-----------+
| id | name  | start_time          | x         |
+----+-------+---------------------+-----------+
|  1 | test1 | 2021-02-21 08:15:00 | 20:15:00  |
|  5 | test5 | 2021-02-23 09:00:00 | 69:00:00  |
|  7 | test7 | 2021-02-23 12:00:00 | 72:00:00  |
|  3 | test3 | 2021-02-24 14:00:00 | 98:00:00  |
|  8 | test8 | 2021-02-15 17:00:00 | 115:00:00 |
|  6 | test6 | 2021-02-26 16:00:00 | 148:00:00 |
|  2 | test2 | 2021-02-11 18:00:00 | 210:00:00 |
|  4 | test4 | 2021-02-10 10:30:00 | 241:30:00 |
+----+-------+---------------------+-----------+
```